# Apple Script / imessage

Tags: applescript

Just starting to apple script here and looking for some help.. I'm trying to create an IF statement using apple script but just cant seem to get it to work.

The plan is to send a imessage and attach a file if the script is executed with the file specified, if not, just send the text.

For Example:

Text only Example:
imessage 5555555555 "hi" "NoAttachment"

Text + File Example:
imessage 5555555555 "hi" "/location/test.jpg"

This is the script I'm using: 
https://gist.github.com/aktau/8958054

But with the following changed at the bottom:

```
on run {targetBuddyPhone, targetMessage, targetFile}
tell application "Messages"
    -- if Messages.app was not running, launch it
    set wasRunning to true
    if it is not running then
        set wasRunning to false
        launch
        close window 1
        my waitUntilRunning("Messages", 1)
        close window 1
    end if

    -- send the message
    set targetService to 1st service whose service type = iMessage
    set targetBuddy to buddy targetBuddyPhone of targetService
    set targetFileSend to targetFile
    if targetFileSend = "NoAttachment" then
        send targetMessage to targetBuddy
    else
        send POSIX targetFileSend to targetBuddy
        send targetMessage to targetBuddy
    end if 
    -- if the app was not running, close the window
    if not wasRunning
        close window 1
    end if
end tell
end run
```

When I execute the script I get:
1635:1649: syntax error: Expected end of line but found identifier. (-2741)

What am I doing wrong here? Instead of using the trigger "NoAttachment" would a nullvalue be better to use?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Try adding the word... "file" .. After "POSIX" `send POSIX file targetFileSend to targetBuddy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the job:

```
send POSIX file targetFileSend to targetBuddy
```